# Run Find & Replace tool on multiple Word Documents (Office 2003)

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2003, find-and-replace

How can I run the Find & Replace tool on multiple Word documents (whether open or closed, doesn't matter to me) in Office 2003?  Thanks!

OS is Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a macro tool and running it on each document...works terrific!

http://www.officeletter.com/favtips/wordmacros.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this tool (Word VBA addon): [VBA Find & Replace](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html)

This tool lets you use a custom replacement list of word pairs in Word or Excel format to process either a single document or batch process multiple Word documents.